# Вложенность ресурсов

Tags: modx, html, php

Такой вопрос, есть ли разница для поисковика как будут оформлены ссылки.

Так:

> domain.com/**category**/resources.html

или так:

> domain.com/resources.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть пользователи, которые вручную поправляют URL. У тебя существует страница domain.com/category ? Если да, то формат ссылки не важен. Если нет, но сделай без указания директории.
2. Поисковику желательны статические ссылки и наличие в них ключевых слов, но это не обязательно.

Расширение имени файла ".html" - это на самом деле статический файл или тебе просто хочется чтобы у ссылок были такие окончания имён страниц? Эта приписка никакого смысла не несёт.

Comment: Да не, окночание страниц не важно, я просто хотел узнать что лучше для поисковиков, когда в адресе есть категория или нету, или может поисковику как то пофиг? Ну и так же для пользователей, что лучше ?

Comment: Я уже спросил: у тебя существует страница domain.com/category ?

Comment: Большинству пользователей всё равно: они про строку адреса не догадываются, они видят только закладки и анкоры (текст, который между `<a>` и `</a>`.

Comment: Да, domain.com/category имеется